# Does Dijkstra's algorithm not modify the distance of a marked vertex?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, path-finding

I recall reading that once Dijkstra's algorithm marks a node as visited, it does not update its distance again. Consider the following graph:

```
A-3-B-7-F
|       |
8     -3
|    /
C-3-E
```

The algorithm would visit A → B → C, and E and F would be queued. But F will be picked first, since it has a smaller distance. Then E would be picked and a shorter distance to F will be found. In this case, shouldn't F's distance be modified even though it is already marked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph has a negative edge weight, -3.

Dijkstra's algorithm does not work when there are negative edge weights. The graph you give in your question is a sufficient example to demonstrate this fact.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Description):

> Unlike Dijkstra's algorithm, the [Bellman–Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) can be used on graphs with negative edge weights, as long as the graph contains no [negative cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_cycle) reachable from the source vertex s.

Comment: Ah I had confused this aspect of Djikstra with Bellman ford's then. I remembered reading that negative edges were allowed in Bellman ford but not cycles but confused it with djikstra's. Thanks.